# Data is not inserting by PDO

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo, autosave

I'm trying to create autosave form in `PHP` through `PDO` everything was working fine in the beginning but after completing it's not working now.
P.S: I created my script by the help of this POST : {[Click to see](http://www.rrpowered.com/2014/07/auto-save-a-draft-with-php-and-jquery/)}

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="ePHP/addNewStory.php">
            <input type="text" name="storyDate" value="<?php echo date("j-n-Y"); ?>" placeholder="<?php echo date("j-n-Y"); ?>"/>
            <input type="file" name="storyImage" id="input-file-now image"  class="dropify" accept='image/*'/>
            <input type="text" name="storyImageTitle"/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="storyComments" checked class="js-switch col-lg-6" data-color="#86c34a"  />                            
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Publish</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-inverse model_img" id="sa-warning">Cancel</button>
            <input type="text" name="storyPublisher" hidden value="1">
            <input type="text" name="storyTitle" >
            <input type="text" name="storyExcerpt">
            <textarea name="editor1" class="Detail"></textarea>
            <input type="text" name="storyAuthor"/>
            <select  name="storyCategory[]" class="select2 select2-multiple" multiple="multiple">
                <optgroup label="Home">
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
                    <option value="CA">California</option>
                    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
                    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
                    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </form>
```

**JS**

```
<script>  
$(function () {
    $.post("ePHP/addNewStory.php", function (data) {
        $("[name='storyPublisher']").val(data.storyPublisher);
        $("[name='storyTitle']").val(data.storyTitle);
        $("[name='storyExcerpt']").val(data.storyExcerpt);
        $("[name='editor1']").val(data.editor1);
        $("[name='storyCategory[]']").val(data.storyCategory);
        $("[name='storyDate']").val(data.storyDate);
        $("[name='storyImageTitle']").val(data.storyImageTitle);
    }, "json");
    setInterval(function () {
        $.post("ePHP/addNewStory.php", $("form").serialize());
    }, 2000);
}); 
</script>
```

**PHP** (addNewStory.php)

```
<?php
session_start();
try {
$dc = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=UPmain", 'root', 'root');
$dc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$storyTitle=$_POST['storyTitle'];
$storyExcerpt=$_POST['storyExcerpt'];
$editor1=$_POST['editor1'];
$storyCategory=$_POST['storyCategory'];
$storyDate=$_POST['storyDate'];
$storyImageTitle=$_POST['storyImageTitle'];
$storyCategory=implode(',', $storyCategory);
$storyPublisher=1;  


$stmt = $dc->query("SELECT * FROM storyAutoSave WHERE storyPublisher='$storyPublisher'");
$return_count = $stmt->rowCount();
if($return_count > 0){     

if(isset($storyTitle)){
    $update_qry = $dc->prepare("UPDATE storyAutoSave SET storyTitle=:storyTitle, storyExcerpt=:storyExcerpt, storyDetail=:editor1, storyCategory=:storyCategory, storyDate=:storyDate, storyImageTitle=:storyImageTitle WHERE storyPublisher='$storyPublisher'");
    $update_qry -> bindValue(':storyTitle', $storyTitle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update_qry -> bindValue(':storyExcerpt', $storyExcerpt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update_qry -> bindValue(':editor1', $editor1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update_qry -> bindValue(':storyCategory', $storyCategory, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update_qry -> bindValue(':storyDate', $storyDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update_qry -> bindValue(':storyImageTitle', $storyImageTitle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $update_qry -> execute(); 
     } else {
    $get_autosave = $dc->prepare("SELECT * FROM storyAutoSave WHERE storyPublisher='$storyPublisher'");
    $get_autosave->execute();
    while ($gt_v = $get_autosave->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $storyTitle=$gt_v['storyTitle'];
        $storyExcerpt=$gt_v['storyExcerpt']; 
        $storyDetail=$gt_v['storyDetail'];
        $storyCategory=$gt_v['storyCategory'];
        $storyDate=$gt_v['storyDate'];
        $storyImageTitle=$gt_v['storyImageTitle'];
        echo json_encode(array('storyTitle' => $storyTitle, 'storyExcerpt' => $storyExcerpt, 'editor1' => $storyDetail, 'storyCategory' => $storyCategory, 'storyDate' => $storyDate, 'storyImageTitle' => $storyImageTitle));
    }           
}
} else { 
$insert_qry = $dc->prepare("INSERT INTO storyAutoSave (storyPublisher, storyTitle, storyExcerpt, storyDetail, storyCategory, storyDate, storyImageTitle) VALUES (storyPublisher=:storyPublisher, storyTitle=:storyTitle, storyExcerpt=:storyExcerpt, storyDetail=:editor1, storyCategory=:storyCategory, storyDate=:storyDate, storyImageTitle=:storyImageTitle)");
$insert_qry -> bindValue(':storyTitle', $storyTitle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_qry -> bindValue(':storyExcerpt', $storyExcerpt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_qry -> bindValue(':editor1', $editor1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_qry -> bindValue(':storyCategory', $storyCategory, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_qry -> bindValue(':storyDate', $storyDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_qry -> bindValue(':storyImageTitle', $storyImageTitle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_qry -> bindValue(':storyPublisher', $storyPublisher, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_qry->execute();  
}
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I also tried this:

```
$insert_qry = $dc->prepare("INSERT INTO storyAutoSave (storyPublisher, storyTitle, storyExcerpt, storyDetail, storyCategory, storyDate, storyImageTitle) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insert_qry->bindParam(1, $storyPublisher);
$insert_qry->bindParam(2, $storyTitle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_qry->bindParam(3, $storyExcerpt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_qry->bindParam(4, $editor1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_qry->bindParam(5, $storyCategory, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_qry->bindParam(6, $storyDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_qry->bindParam(7, $storyImageTitle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert_qry->execute();
```

And `addNewStory.php` give me that error : `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'storyTitle' cannot be null`

**When I am inserting value in column "storyPublisher" in database, everything start working**

Comment: `Column 'storyTitle' cannot be null` says it all.. if the column can accept null value change it to become nullable to solve the issue

Comment: @guradio did you mean in `database`?

Comment: yes change that in database and it will be ok

Comment: I got your point!

Comment: is working now?

Comment: Yes I change all my column from `NOT NULL` to `NULL`

Comment: you can change column to nullable to only columns that may have null have but for columns you know that will always have values you cant set to to not nullable

Comment: Yes I know that I mean to say that I made those column `Nullable` who will have some value after filling form.